# Java Generics confusion regarding constructors

Tags: java, generics

Why do the following code samples fail to compile?

Sample-1

```
public class Generic5<T extends Comparable, Runnable> {
    T t;
    Comparable comparable;

    Generic5(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    Generic5(Comparable comparable) {
        this.comparable = comparable;
    }
}
```

Sample-2

```
public class Generic4<T extends Runnable, Comparable> {
    T t;
    Runnable runnable;

    Generic4(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    Generic4(Runnable runnable) {
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }
}
```

while the following code samples compile successfully?

Sample-4

```
public class Generic4<T extends Runnable, Comparable> {
    T t;
    Comparable comparable;

    Generic4(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    Generic4(Comparable comparable) {
        this.comparable = comparable;
    }
}
```

Sample-5

```
public class Generic5<T extends Comparable, Runnable> {
    T t;
    Runnable runnable;

    Generic5(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    Generic5(Runnable runnable) {
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }
}
```

Sample-6

```
public class Generic6<T extends Number, Comparable, Runnable> {
    T t;
    Comparable comparable;

    Generic6(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    Generic6(Comparable comparable) {
        this.comparable = comparable;
    }
}
```

Sample-7

```
public class Generic6<T extends Number, Comparable, Runnable> {
    T t;
    Runnable runnable;

    Generic6(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    Generic6(Runnable runnable) { 
        this.runnable = runnable; 
    }
}
```

I am not able to understand why there is no issue with erasure in case of Sample 4, 5, 6 and 7 while it is there in case of Sample 1 and 2.

I am using Java 8. I would appreciate a separate explanation for each sample.

Comment: What exactly is the compiler error?

Comment: Because the constructors have the same erasure. Compiler would have told you that.

Comment: @AndyTurner - Thanks for your comment. Yes, compiler had told about erasure. However, if you have some time to look at Sample 1,2,4, 5 and 8, you will be able to understand the cause of confusion.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I don't find it confusing, though. I don't say that to belittle you, I'm just saying that I understand the reason, but don't know what exactly you do and don't understand. You should say exactly what about it you find confusing, so you can get a specific answer.

Comment: @AndyTurner - Thanks for your feedback. I am not able to understand why there is no issue with erasure in case of Sample 4, 5, 6 and 7 while it is there in Sample 1 and 2.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash firstly, if you are confused by just those examples (or primarily confused by them) remove the others, they are just noise. Secondly: do you understand that erasure is something that happens only to type variables: what are the type variables in these examples, and what is their erasure?

Comment: Warning: you are using existing well-known class names as names of type parameters. Type parameters consist almost always of a single letter. Did you mean `Generic<T extends Runnable, U extends Comparable>`?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I am fairly confident that this entire question is just confusion. I assume you want `T` to extend both `Comparable` and `Runnable`. Right now, this is not the case. If you want that, use the expression `T extends Comparable & Runnable`. In your examples you are actually specifying 2/3 _different_ generic types. Read this article: [Bounded Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)

Comment: @Obicere - If I am not wrong, `T extends Comparable & Runnable` can be used only inside method declaration.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash the article I linked to specifically uses it on classes. Try compiling this code: [sratch.java](https://gist.github.com/56ffb7b26a2fc183d8b74a1b1c75dc86)

Comment: Thanks, @Obicere. I learnt this new thing from you. Any idea, why Sample 1 and 2 fail to compile why Sample 4, 5, 6 and 7 compile successfully?

Comment: Reading all this code i get one thing that you cannot create a constructor of same type which is extended first. But Why IDK? If someone can explain that will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through the comments, this appears to just be a misunderstanding of the `,` symbol when it comes to generics.

Consider the following two statements:

```
class A <T extends B, C> { ... }
```

And

```
class X <U extends Y & Z> { ... }
```

In the first case, there would be 2 type parameters specified:

1. `T`, which extends `B`
2. `C`, which extends `java.lang.Object`

Therefore, to use `A`, one would have to specify the type like so:

```
A<B, Object> myA = new A<>();
myA.myMethod();
```

As you can see, there are 2 generic types that are needed.

---

Contrasting that is the second case, where there is 1 type parameter specified:

1. `U`, which extends `Y` and `Z`

To use this, one would have to specify the type like so:

```
class MyClass extends Y implements Z { ... }

// ...

X<MyClass> myX = new X<>();
myX.myMethod();
```

In this case, only one generic type is needed. That type *must* be of type `Y` and `Z`, hence why `MyClass` was created to fulfill this requirement.

---

By looking at your question, I am assuming you meant to specify the second behavior; but, you accidentally specified the first.

So if we consider Sample-1, it should be clear why it fails. By removing the generic types (type erasure, something the compiler has to do) sample 1 would effectively become:

```
public class Generic5 {
    Comparable t;
    Comparable comparable;

    Generic5(Comparable t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    Generic5(Comparable comparable) {
        this.comparable = comparable;
    }
}
```

Now if we call one of the constructors with type `Comparable`, which should the JVM execute? The Java compiler can't tell. This is why this sample can't be compiled. The Java compiler has an issue with how this was specified.

Note: in Sample-1, the `Runnable` type is *not* `java.lang.Runnable`. You have accidentally created a new generic type with the same name. This `Runnable` would actually become `java.lang.Object`!

This is effectively the same behavior as specifying the type to be:

```
public class Generic5<T extends Comparable, U> { ... }
```

---

Now, if we consider Sample-5, and perform type erasure, we can see why this sample works. Sample-5 will become:

```
public class Generic5 {
    Comparable t;
    Object runnable;

    Generic5(Comparable t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    Generic5(Object runnable) {
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }
}
```

Now, the compiler will happily accept this code!

As before, `Runnable` is a new type you created and will be replaced with `java.lang.Object`, *not* `java.lang.Runnable`.

---

So lets try to fix Sample-1. The immediate solution would be to use [Multiple Type Parameter Bounds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html). This would then make the class look like (note the usage of `&` on the first line):

```
public class Generic5<T extends Comparable & Runnable> {
    T t;
    Comparable comparable;

    Generic5(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    Generic5(Comparable comparable) {
        this.comparable = comparable;
    }
}
```

Now, `T` must be of type `java.lang.Comparable` and `java.lang.Runnable`. We managed to make `T` more specific. We also made sure that we are actually using `java.lang.Runnable` now.

However, this still won't work! The type erasure is still the same as before, except now there is the added usage of `java.lang.Runnable`.

So why does this fail? Well, it has to do with the order of the types. Since `java.lang.Comparable` appears first, you are guiding the Java compiler by saying the primary characteristic of `T` is comparable. When it performs type erasure it will replace `T` with `java.lang.Comparable`. In our first solution, we rearrange the order and make the primary characteristic `java.lang.Runnable`, and the compiler accepts our help and everything is fine. In the second, we outright replace `T` with a very specific new type and the Java compiler will appreciate this change even more than the first.

There are two ways to fix this:

### 1. Rearrange Order:

```
public class Generic5<T extends Runnable & Comparable> {
    T t;
    Comparable comparable;

    Generic5(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    Generic5(Comparable comparable) {
        this.comparable = comparable;
    }
}
```

Here, the type erasure will effectively become:

```
public class Generic5 {
    Runnable t;
    Comparable comparable;

    Generic5(Runnable t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    Generic5(Comparable comparable) {
        this.comparable = comparable;
    }
}
```

Which will work fine.

Note: `t` is still guaranteed to be `java.lang.Comparable`, so methods in `java.lang.Comparable` can still be called on `t`.

---

### 2. Specify New Type:

Generics can be dropped in favor of a new type:

```
public class Generic5 {
    MyNewType t;
    Comparable comparable;

    Generic5(MyNewType t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    Generic5(Comparable comparable) {
        this.comparable = comparable;
    }
}

class MyNewType implements Comparable, Runnable { ... }
```

Here, generics have been removed completely. In my opinion, this is the better solution. It adheres closer to Object-Oriented Programming and removes any confusion about the types.

---

### tl;dr

If you want to specify a generic type with multiple bounds, you need to use the `&` operator, not the `,` operator.

Furthermore, the order of the bounds matters when it comes to type erasure. The first bound will be used. If there is still a conflict, rearrange the order, or create a new class that extends the bounds and use that class in place of generics.

Comment: To add onto this, be sure to practice generics. Not only should you create those `Generic5` classes, but you should also create classes that use these generic classes. See how the types must be specified and how they operate outside of the generic class.